# Cannot remove watch expression from Locals and Watchers window in Qt Creator

Tags: qt4, qt-creator

Greetings!

I have a weird problem and i cannot find any answer anywhere on the webs. I have Qt-Creator 2.0.1
Since like a month or more ago, i have a big expression hanging in the "Locals and Watchers" window when i am debugging. It is showing "not accessible" as its value.
If i remove it, it will be removed, but on next change (adding a variable to watch, or deleting another) it will come back. 
If i try to edit it, it behaves like there is nothing there (blank edit box instead of option to edit the expression). 
If i press enter after editing it, another expression will be added (should have replaced this, but it wont).

Problem persists through reboot or restart of Qt-Creator. Is there a way to fix it? Like, where can the debugged be storing those expressions, so i could remove them manually? Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. I wish I could help!

Answer (score 0):

QtCreator workspace configuration is stored in separate file.

```
On Windows platform it is  (User Profile)/Application Data/Nokia/qtcreator/SessionName.qws
On Linux platform it is $HOME/.config/Nokia/qtcreator/SessionName.qws
```

.qws is XML file that contains watched variables.